# Ignite Failed to wait for recovery descriptor reservation

Tags: java, kubernetes, ignite

We are running Ignite within Kubernetes and saw the following error client side.

It looks like at the time some other processes had some difficulty communicating over the network (high latency and time outs).

I think this is likely the root cause of the below Ignite exception but would still like to know if there is any documentation to give more information of what a Failed to wait for recovery descriptor reservation exactly is.

````
12-Jun-2023 14:58:56.811 SEVERE [Timer-15] org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger.error Failed to wait for recovery descriptor reservation [desc=GridNioRecoveryDescriptor [acked=455168, resendCnt=0, rcvCnt=455198, sentCnt=455199, reserved=true, lastAck=455168, nodeLeft=false, node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=************, consistentId=******, addrs=ArrayList [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 127.0.0.1, ******], sockAddrs=HashSet [/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo]:47500, /127.0.0.1:47500, foo-bar-ignite-1-1-0.foo-bar-ignite-1-1.*****.svc.cluster.local/[******]:47500], discPort=47500, order=1, intOrder=1, lastExchangeTime=1686364720306, loc=false, ver=2.11.1#20211220-sha1:eae1147d, isClient=false], connected=false, connectCnt=1, queueLimit=4096, reserveCnt=1, pairedConnections=false], ses=GridSelectorNioSessionImpl [worker=DirectNioClientWorker [super=AbstractNioClientWorker [idx=0, bytesRcvd=4187847680, bytesSent=3335905975, bytesRcvd0=0, bytesSent0=0, select=false, super=GridWorker [name=grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-0, igniteInstanceName=TcpCommunicationSpi, finished=true, heartbeatTs=1686365362565, hashCode=2136585786, interrupted=false, runner=grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-0-#23%TcpCommunicationSpi%]]], writeBuf=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=5560 lim=32768 cap=32768], readBuf=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=32768 cap=32768], inRecovery=GridNioRecoveryDescriptor [acked=455168, resendCnt=0, rcvCnt=455198, sentCnt=455199, reserved=true, lastAck=455168, nodeLeft=false, node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=************, consistentId=******, addrs=ArrayList [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 127.0.0.1, ******], sockAddrs=HashSet [/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo]:47500, /127.0.0.1:47500, foo-bar-ignite-1-1-0.foo-bar-ignite-1-1.*********.svc.cluster.local/[fd00:85:4001:5:9a2a:7c61:5749:de64]:47500], discPort=47500, order=1, intOrder=1, lastExchangeTime=1686364720306, loc=false, ver=2.11.1#20211220-sha1:eae1147d, isClient=false], connected=false, connectCnt=1, queueLimit=4096, reserveCnt=1, pairedConnections=false], outRecovery=GridNioRecoveryDescriptor [acked=455168, resendCnt=0, rcvCnt=455198, sentCnt=455199, reserved=true, lastAck=455168, nodeLeft=false, node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=************, consistentId=******, addrs=ArrayList [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 127.0.0.1, ******], sockAddrs=HashSet [/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo]:47500, /127.0.0.1:47500, foo-bar-ignite-1-1-0.foo-bar-ignite-1-1.c6f362c5-5e67-5b2a-a72f-*******.svc.cluster.local/[*******]:47500], discPort=47500, order=1, intOrder=1, lastExchangeTime=1686364720306, loc=false, ver=2.11.1#20211220-sha1:eae1147d, isClient=false], connected=false, connectCnt=1, queueLimit=4096, reserveCnt=1, pairedConnections=false], closeSocket=true, outboundMessagesQueueSizeMetric=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.metric.impl.LongAdderMetric@69a257d1, super=GridNioSessionImpl [locAddr=/[******]:41956, rmtAddr=foo-bar-ignite-1-1-0.foo-bar-ignite-1-1.*****.svc.cluster.local/[******]:47100, createTime=1686364720981, closeTime=1686365447813, bytesSent=3335905975, bytesRcvd=4187847680, bytesSent0=0, bytesRcvd0=0, sndSchedTime=1686364720981, lastSndTime=1686365359902, lastRcvTime=1686365350069, readsPaused=false, filterChain=FilterChain[filters=[GridNioCodecFilter [parser=org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridDirectParser@747d999d, directMode=true], GridConnectionBytesVerifyFilter], accepted=false, markedForClose=true]]]

12-Jun-2023 14:58:56.811 INFO [Timer-15] org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger.info TCP client created [client=null, node addrs=[foo-bar-ignite-1-1-0.foo-bar-ignite-1-1.*****.svc.cluster.local/[*****]:47100, /[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo]:47100, /127.0.0.1:47100], duration=5001ms]```
````